# Factorial function only returning inputted answer in C++?

Tags: c++, factorial

I have to create a program which calculates the factorial of any number, the problem is if I input any number above 20 it just returns that number. What in my else if statement could be causing this and is there a better way to solve this? ( this function is called in main and works if num <= 20)

```
void factorial() {

//User input for number
long long num;
std::cout << "Input any positive integer to find its factorial: ";
std::cin >> num;

unsigned long long numFact = 1;
if (num <= 20) {

    while (num > 0) {
        numFact = numFact * num;
        num = num - 1;
    }
    std::cout << numFact;
}

else if (num > 20) {

    std::vector<int> multFactorial;

    //stores num as seperate elements in vector multFactorial
    while (num > 0) {
        int remain = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        multFactorial.insert(multFactorial.begin(), remain);
    }
    std::vector<int> answer;
    std::vector<int> answerFinal;

    //Manually multiplies elements in multFactorial
    //Then adds new vectors created by multiplying to get final answer
    //Repeats until factorial is solved
    //Ex: 21 * 20; 0 * 1 and 0 * 2 stored as {0 , 0}
    //2*1 and 2*2 stored as {4, 2, 0}
    //Vectors will be addes to get {4, 2, 0} and then that will be multiplied 
by 19 until num = 1
    while (num > 1) {

        for (int i = multFactorial.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int remain1 = ((num - 1) % 10) * multFactorial[i];
            answer.insert(answer.begin(), remain1);
            int remain2 = (((num - 1) / 10) * multFactorial[i]);
            answerFinal.insert(answerFinal.begin(), remain2);
        }

        answerFinal.insert(answerFinal.begin(), 0);

        //Adds vectors to get final value seperate as digits
        for (int i = multFactorial.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            multFactorial[i] = answer[i] + answerFinal[i];
        }
        num = num - 1;

    }
    //Prints what should be the factorial of the number input
    for (size_t i = 0; i < multFactorial.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << multFactorial[i];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a special condition for `num > 20`? Does the math of how we calculate factorial change?

Comment: @scohe001 It's simple to find the factorial of 20! or below, but c++ can't store any number's factorial past that, so I would have to use a different method. I could use the same method for all numbers, but I don't think it would matter.

Comment: Ahh I see. If you use your "more complex" method for *all* numbers it'll make it easier to debug since you'll be able to follow the math on say 6! as opposed to 21! ;)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. Debugging your own code is an important skill in programming. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/.

Comment: Also, quick tip....after your loop to populate `multFactorial`, `num` will always be `0`. The next thing you do is enter a loop whose condition is `while (num > 1)`...

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will help you step through your code, watching values in variables.  Often, using a debugger is faster than correctly posting to StackOverflow and *waiting* for somebody else to inspect or debug your program for you.  Please edit your post with the text results of your debugging session.

Comment: `if (num > 20)` in `else if (num > 20)` is unnecessary since the other condition is `if (num <= 20)`.

Comment: "is there a better way to solve this?"  in what way better?  For "ease of use" I choose Gnu MP's  mpz_class, a multi-precision  integer, and the obvious for loop.  20 Factorial takes 2 us and generates 19 digit value.  100,000 factorial takes 1.7 seconds, and generates 456,574 digit (unreadable) value.

Answer (score 1):

Factorials of large numbers results in huge numbers. This can be accommodated in languages like C, C++ etc by putting the results into arbitrary length strings.

Here is an algorithm for that - similar to yours.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-large-number/

Best advice is to check your code against this.
Use a debugger if you have one and step through the code line by line.
If not print out intermediate results and compare with expected.

**EDIT:** As per review comment, the code at above ref is similar to below- just in case link is broken in future.

```
// C++ program to compute factorial of big numbers
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// Maximum number of digits in output
#define MAX 100   // change to whatever value you need

int multiply(int x, int res[], int res_size);

// Calculate factorial of large number
void factorial(int n)
{
    int res[MAX];

    // Initialize result
    res[0] = 1;
    int res_size = 1;

    // Apply factorial formula
    for (int x=2; x<=n; x++)
        res_size = multiply(x, res, res_size);

    // print out the result 
    cout << "Factorial is \n";
    for (int i=res_size-1; i>=0; i--)
        cout << res[i];
}

// Multiplies x with the number represented by res[].
// res_size is size of res[] or number of digits in the 
// number represented by res[]. 

int multiply(int x, int res[], int res_size)
{
    int carry = 0;  // Initialize carry

    // One by one multiply n with individual digits of res[]
    for (int i=0; i<res_size; i++)
    {
        int prod = res[i] * x + carry;

        // Store last digit of 'prod' in res[]  
        res[i] = prod % 10;  

        // Put rest in carry
        carry  = prod/10;    
    }

    // Put carry in res and increase result size
    while (carry)
    {
        res[res_size] = carry%10;
        carry = carry/10;
        res_size++;
    }
    return res_size;
}

// Main program
int main()
{
    //put code here to read a number

    factorial(50); // take 50 for example
    return 0;
}
```